# Expected declaration in Swift if/else statement

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
        if userData != nil {
        self.initUserInfo()

        self.retreiveOrderCount()
        self.retreiveWatchCount()
        self.retreiveFollowingCount()
    } else {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginview")

        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This is the code block that is giving me the expected declaration.

Comment: Either there is a missing curly brace `{ or }` or you've added an extra curly brace. Hard to say without the whole function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra bracket at the end. Remove the bracket just like bellow:

```
if userData != nil {
        self.initUserInfo()

        self.retreiveOrderCount()
        self.retreiveWatchCount()
        self.retreiveFollowingCount()
    } else {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginview")

        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```